# Iterate through nested lists & dictionaries to get grouping of one value by another

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, iteration

I am working to create a program which will generate today's news for each stock in my portfolio every time I run it. I have successfully downloaded the news for the portfolio's stocks, and to my knowledge it is presented as a list of dictionaries. Here is an example output of AAPL's news for today, so you can see the format: This was created using headlines[0] (headlines contains all of the news articles and their parameters)

```
[{'uuid': '5be16b13-a550-3b19-bfc7-6db8f78ae01c',
  'title': "Apple to host annual developers' conference from June 5",
  'publisher': 'Reuters',
  'link': 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-host-annual-developers-conference-173217646.html',
  'providerPublishTime': 1680111137,
  'type': 'STORY',
  'thumbnail': {'resolutions': [{'url': 'https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/vTSqzTi3XOE4.NVOu2KeKQ--~B/aD01MzM7dz04MDA7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media.zenfs.com/en/reuters-finance.com/c52dd0fd2a1bb097651c5fa27fc7a3d9',
     'width': 800,
     'height': 533,
     'tag': 'original'},
    {'url': 'https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/F4MkRNXpiOMZVqhwa4V9ug--~B/Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTE0MDtweW9mZj0wO3c9MTQwO2FwcGlkPXl0YWNoeW9u/https://media.zenfs.com/en/reuters-finance.com/c52dd0fd2a1bb097651c5fa27fc7a3d9',
     'width': 140,
     'height': 140,
     'tag': '140x140'}]},
  'relatedTickers': ['AAPL']}
```

There are 8 total articles for AAPL, and there are different numbers of articles for each stock.
I am only interested in pulling the titles of the article for each stock.

My code is formatted as such:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'ABB', 'AIG', 'AMR', 'CB', 'COLD', 'COOP', 'COST', 'CRM', 'CVS', 'DBOEY', 'DG', 'DIS', 'ENPH', 'F', 'GOOG',
          'JPM', 'LMT', 'LULU', 'LVMUY', 'MSFT', 'NHYDY', 'NKE', 'OXY', 'PG', 'QCOM', 'RTX', 'SBGSY', 'SHEL', 'STZ', 'TM',
          'TMUS', 'TSM', 'UPS', 'VEEV', 'WMT', 'ZTS']
yf_objects = []
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    yf_objects.append(ticker)

headlines = []
for i in yf_objects:
    headlines.append(i.news)
```

The only way I am able to isolate the title so far for one entry for one stock at a time is by:

```
headlines[0][0]['title']
```

Which returns AAPL (first 0 index), the first article (second 0 index), and the title ['title'].
However, this would ruin the point of this small project if I had to manually run each article for each stock.

I have tried nested for loops with no success, and would greatly appreciate help in finding a way to loop through each ticker in the tickers list, each article for each ticker, and only pull the title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been working on this problem for two hours (I am a beginner coder), and once I figure this out it would be of much help to me personally.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is your desired output? A dictionary with the tickers as keys and list of article names as the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify what you're doing a little bit to get a dict where the keys are tickers and the values are lists of articles. Something like this...

```py
import yfinance as yf

output_dict = {}
tickers = ['AAPL', 'ABB', 'AIG', ...]
for ticker in tickers:
    yf_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    output_dict[ticker] = [news['title'] for news in yf_ticker.news]
```

gives you...

```py
{'AAPL': ['Today’s top stories: Bank regulator hearing, Starbucks CEO testimony, Apple Developers Conference',
  'Best Streaming Devices: Google Chromecast, Apple TV, Amazon Fire and More',
  'Apple announces its annual conference dates in June, hinting unveil of VR headset',
  'Apple Sets June Dates for Developer Conference',
  'Apple TV Could Allow Viewers To View Multiple Sports Simultaneously After Rival Launches Similar Feature',
  "Apple to host annual developers' conference from June 5",
  'How Microsoft And Google Beat Apple And Amazon To The Top In Generative AI',
  'Apple’s Worldwide Developers Conference returns June 5, 2023'],
 'ABB': ['ABB to Launch New Share Buyback Program of up to $1B in April',
  'ABB Invests $20M to Expand Robotics Facility in Auburn Hills',
  "Has ABB Ltd (VTX:ABBN) Stock's Recent Performance Got Anything to Do With Its Financial Health?",
  'ABB Ramps Up Investment In Its Robotics Facility In US',
  "ABB Shares Up 17% in 6 Months: What's Driving the Stock?",
  'ABB to expand Robotics factory in US',
  '11 Cheap EV Stocks To Buy',
  'ABB Collaborates With DEP to Promote Energy Transformation'],
 'AIG': ['Those who invested in American International Group (NYSE:AIG) three years ago are up 101%',
  'American International Group, Inc. (NYSE:AIG) insiders who sold US$918k worth of stock earlier this year are probably glad they did so as market cap slides to US$35b',
  'Should You Hold American International Group (AIG) For Long-Term Returns?',
  'Meta’s Layoffs Are Just a Drop in the Bucket. These Companies Cut More.',
  'From Bear Stearns to Credit Suisse: Crises, Mergers and Bailouts',
  'American International Group (AIG) Down 19.3% Since Last Earnings Report: Can It Rebound?',
  "American International Group, Inc.'s (NYSE:AIG) Fundamentals Look Pretty Strong: Could The Market Be Wrong About The Stock?",
  'William G. Jurgensen to Retire from the AIG Board of Directors'],
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the most efficient, but hopefully easy to understand:

```py
# If this is what you have (removed irrelevant keys)
headlines = [
 {'title': "Apple to host annual developers' conference from June 5",
  'relatedTickers': ['AAPL']},
 {'title': "Title2",
  'relatedTickers': ['AAPL']},
 {'title': "Title3",
  'relatedTickers': ['AAPL', 'AMZN']},
]

# Sounds like you're looking for:
all_tickers = {ticker for headline in headlines for ticker in headline['relatedTickers']}
headlines_by_ticker = {
    ticker: [headline['title'] for headline in headlines if ticker in headline['relatedTickers']]
    for ticker in all_tickers
}
```

which gives:

```py
{'AMZN': ['Title3'],
 'AAPL': ["Apple to host annual developers' conference from June 5",
  'Title2',
  'Title3']}
```

Since you're a beginner coder, here's a different implementation that does the same thing, in case you find this easier to understand.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

headlines_by_ticker = defaultdict(list)
for headline in headlines:
    for ticker in headline['relatedTickers']:
        headlines_by_ticker[ticker].append(headline['title'])
```